# CakePHP: change Js Helper setVariable

Tags: javascript, cakephp, helper

how do I change the settings e.g. the variable of CakePHP's Js Helper?
I would say something like this:

```
class AppController extends Controller {
  public $helpers = array('Js' => array('setVariable' => 'foo'));
```

But it has no effect.

`echo $this->Js->writeBuffer(…);` in my View still has this output: `window.app = { … }` instead of: `window.foo = { … }`

I can't figure out what's wrong :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I solved it myself. I added `$this->Js->setVariable = 'APP';` in my View just before calling `echo $this->Js->writeBuffer(…);`